# flutter: How to show weather data on dialog box

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
How to show weather data on dialog box.
please help me

this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:weather/weather.dart';

enum AppState { NOT_DOWNLOADED, DOWNLOADING, FINISHED_DOWNLOADING }


class MyAppp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyApppState createState() => _MyApppState();
}

class _MyApppState extends State<MyAppp> {
  String key = '856822fd8e22db5e1ba48c0e7d69844a';
  late WeatherFactory ws;
  List<Weather> _data = [];
  AppState _state = AppState.NOT_DOWNLOADED;
  // double? lat, lon;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ws = new WeatherFactory(key);
  }

  void queryWeather() async {
    /// Removes keyboard
    var position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    var lat = position.latitude;
    var long = position.longitude;
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

    setState(() {

      _state = AppState.DOWNLOADING;
    });

    Weather weather = await ws.currentWeatherByLocation(lat!, long!);
    setState(() {
      _data = [weather];
      _state = AppState.FINISHED_DOWNLOADING;
    });
  }



  // Widget _resultView() => _state == AppState.FINISHED_DOWNLOADING
  //     ? contentFinishedDownload()
  //     : _state == AppState.DOWNLOADING
  //     ? contentDownloading()
  //     : contentNotDownloaded();


  Widget _buttons() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: TextButton(
            child: Text(
              'Fetch weather',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed:() {
              queryWeather();
          showDialog<String>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return _state == AppState.FINISHED_DOWNLOADING? Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 500,
              width: 320,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: _data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(_data[index].toString()),
                  );
                },
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Divider();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ):Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          });
            },
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue)),
          ),
        ),
        
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Weather Example App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            // _coordinateInputs(),
            _buttons(),
            Text(
              'Output:',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 20.0,
              thickness: 2.0,
            ),
            // Expanded(child: _resultView())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean an AlertDialog box? If so try this example first. It shows how to spawn an alert box. https://googleflutter.com/flutter-alertdialog/

Comment: @James ok but how to set Weather report data , first my data will load after that I wanna show data in alertBox

Comment: that will be the next step. If the data doesn't take long I would suggest looking in to using async/await until the data is returned, and only then update the state.